# Hello! My algorithm does not work for n>7 and I don't know why

Tags: c++, tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I built a perfectly balaced tree using BUILD_TREE and printed it inOrder and using a PRETTY_PRINT. The keys for my tree are in a sorted array named arr and I use n as the number of keys. If I give n a value bigger that 7 it does not print anything and I don't understand why. I need it to work for n=11.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>     
#define NR_SPATII 7
#define MAX_SIZE 20
using namespace std;

typedef struct Tree {
    int key;
    struct Tree* left;
    struct Tree* right;
    int size;
}Tree;

Tree* createNewNode(int givenkey)
{
    Tree* node = (Tree*)malloc(sizeof(Tree));
    node->key = givenkey;
    node->left = NULL;
    node->right = NULL;
    node->size = NULL;
    return node;
}

Tree* BUILD_TREE(int arr[], int low, int high)
{
    int s = 1;
    if (low > high)
        return NULL;

    int mid = (low + high) / 2;
    Tree* node = createNewNode(mid);
    node->left = BUILD_TREE(arr, low, mid - 1);
    node->right = BUILD_TREE(arr, mid + 1, high);

    if (low == high)
        node->size = 1;
    else node->size = node->left->size + node->right->size + 1;

    return node;
}

void PRETTY_PRINT(Tree* root, int nivel)
{
    if (root == NULL)
        return;
    nivel += NR_SPATII; //crestem distanta intre nivele
    PRETTY_PRINT(root->right, nivel);//procesam copilul drept
    printf("\n");
    for (int i = NR_SPATII; i < nivel; i++)
        printf(" ");
    printf("%d,%d\n", root->key, root->size);//scriem nodul dupa spatiu
    PRETTY_PRINT(root->left, nivel);
}

void inOrder(Tree* root)
{
    if (root != NULL) {
        inOrder(root->left);
        printf("%d,%d  ", root->key, root->size);
        inOrder(root->right);
    }
}

void demo()
{
    int n = 7;
    int arr[MAX_SIZE];
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        arr[i] = i;

    Tree* root = (Tree*)malloc(sizeof(Tree));
    root = BUILD_TREE(arr, 1, n);
    printf("AFISARE INORDINE:\n");
    inOrder(root);
    printf("\nAFISARE PRETTY PRINT:");
    PRETTY_PRINT(root, 0);
}

int main()
{
    demo();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Here's the deal. You have two test cases: one that works and one that does not. These are the perfect ingredients for a productive debugging session. Give the broken input to your program, and step through its execution one line at a time in the debugger. You will quickly find any place where reality does not match expectation.

Comment: Pick **a** language. From what i see, this is C code, save for one oddly placed "using namespace std;" . Unrelated, `node->size = NULL;` is not your problem, but is conceptual nonsense. Presumably, that should be `node->size = 0;`

Comment: You need to learn to identify the difference between your program "not printing anything" and your program _crashing_. Running with size 11 results in a segfault on line 37 where you dereference a NULL pointer: https://godbolt.org/z/44P8KTohd

Comment: `Tree* node = (Tree*)malloc(sizeof(Tree));` -- `typedef struct Tree` -- This is C code, or you got this code from a `C` website or book.  No C++ book would introduce usage of `malloc` this way.  At the very least, the book would use `new[]`.

Comment: But in C the `(Tree*)` cast is redundant. No one would write C code like that!

Comment: @user4581301 No one except 90% of SO posters, and the people/tutorials they learned from.

Comment: When I see **does not work for n>7** and then `#define NR_SPATII 7` I immediately wonder if I should more closely examine how `NR_SPATII` is being used.

Comment: @Barmar until I better understood the scope of Stack Overflow and how broad the umbrella of users was, I took pride in being in the top 1% of users. Now I know your 90% estimate is probably too low.

Comment: Thank you so much everyone! I read all the comments and managed to find the problem and now it works. I learned the (Tree*) cast from school. The problem was  node->size = node->left->size + node->right->size + 1; because node->left and node->right could be NULL as you said. Thank you!

Comment: Apologies for trying to be funny earlier. The `(tree*)` case (or more correctly a `reinterpret_cast<tree*>` cast) is necessary in C++ because C++ checks that types match more closely than the C language does, and must be nudged when you want to do something potentially stupid. Be really careful with these types of casts because the compiler treats them like the word of God. It shuts up and compiles no matter how bad an idea it may turn out to be. Unless you're careful these casts turn compiler errors that you can immediately see into runtime errors that you'll have to find the hard way.

Comment: What `(Tree*)malloc(sizeof(Tree));`'s cast is doing here is telling the compiler to allow the anonymous blob of raw memory returned by `malloc` to be treated like a `Tree`.  This is safe here because `Tree` is so simple. Try this with a more complicated class like `std::string` (which isn't necessarily all that complicated) and the program will misbehave. `malloc`'s blob of memory is NOT a `std::string` until the `std::string`'s constructor has been run, so telling the compiler that the blob is safe to use as a `string` is a flat-out lie. We see questions about this mistake daily.

Comment: Thank you for explaining. I still have problems with pointers and with allowing memory but I hope as time goes I will understand them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running your program in a debugger should instantly identify the problem as this line in `BUILD_TREE`:

```
else node->size = node->left->size + node->right->size + 1;
```

The issue is that the `left` or `right` pointers can be NULL. If they are, you will most likely crash. Dereferencing a NULL pointer and reading (or writing) to that memory is undefined behavior.

You can replace this:

```
if (low == high)
    node->size = 1;
else node->size = node->left->size + node->right->size + 1;
```

With this:

```
node->size = 1
    + (node->left ? node->left->size : 0)
    + (node->right ? node->right->size : 0);
```

That means if a subtree is NULL, it will be considered to have size zero, and crucially you will not dereference that pointer.

Alternatively you can define a function that returns a tree size and handles NULL-testing internally:

```
int TreeSize(const Tree* tree)
{
    return tree ? tree->size : 0;
}
```

Then your calculation becomes a bit neater:

```
node->size = 1 + TreeSize(node->left) + TreeSize(node->right);
```

Comment: Side note: By long-standing convention ALL_CAPS identifiers like `BUILD_TREE` should be reserved for macros as a warning to users that text substitution is in play.

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't know that could be the problem but I solved it thanks to you!